# First Two Pages using same value in View pager of Android. How to disable it?

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the data from the database by using the current position of the view pager in android, but when I tried it, first two pages uses the same number. Is there any way to use current position of the pager to retrieve the data?

```
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {          
    int a = arg0 + 1;
}
```

### I passed the value of 'a', but second page also used the value a as 1 in view pager.

I used the following in the fragment,

DBMain dbm1 = new DBMain(context); dbm1.open();

```
    Cursor cursor = dbm1.getSGGS(no);//'no' is the number 'a'
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

            array.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("abc")));


            cursor.moveToNext();
```

}

But the first two will use 'a' as 1. I want to make the second fragment to use 'a' as 2 and then 3......

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Share some more code..adapter etc

Comment: @Faizan Added the detailed code

Comment: Where are you passing the value 'a'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleared the error. Get the value on onCreate instead of onCreateView.

Thanks for the reply